# Inheriting user controls in C# .NET 2010

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working on a program in C# .NET 2010 using WinForms and am having difficulty inheriting the System.windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart class into a custom chart.

When I view the form in the Visual Studio designer, I get an error saying:

> Could not find type 'ExpeView.ExpeDataChart'. Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

The file ExpeDataChart.cs is part of this project, and whenever I compile and run the program, it works perfectly. This error only comes up in the designer view, making it impossible for me to edit the form through the GUI.

The file ExpeDataChart.cs looks like this (this is slimmed down, but gets the point across):

```
namespace ExpeView
{
    public class ExpeDataChart : Chart
    {
        public ExpeDataChart()
        {
            MouseMove += SampleMouseMove;
            MouseLeave += SampleMouseLeave;
            MouseDoubleClick += SampleDoubleClick;
            MouseDown += SampleMouseDown;
            MouseUp += SampleMouseUp;
            MouseEnter += SampleMouseEnter;
            MouseLeave += SampleMouseLeave;
            MouseWheel += SampleMouseWheel;
        }

        private void SampleMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleMouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { }
        private void SampleZoomIn(int x) { }
        private void SampleZoomOut() { }
    }
}
```

What would cause it to not properly load in the designer, but still load properly when compiling? The call stack of the error is:

> ExpeView FormExpeView.Designer.cs Line:438 Column:1 at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.Error(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String exceptionText, String helpLink) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeExpression(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, String name, CodeExpression expression) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializeStatement(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager, CodeStatement statement)

Comment: I was trying to quickly recreate the issue, but it seemed to work correctly. It looks like there may be an error in the *Designer* file of the form. Have You tried to remove the control from the form (in the code in *FormExpeView.Designer.cs* file)? After removing the control from the form, rebuild the project, verify that You can show the designer of the form and then add the control again through the designer.

Comment: I did do this and it worked properly. groverboy gave me a working solution though - put ExpeDataChart.cs into a separate project from the form.

Comment: In a test project, I added the control to the same project as the form is and the designer worked correctly. I suppose the issue was caused by something else (maybe some old code in the designer file), which might have been automatically resolved as a result of changing the control's location.

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2010 and WinForms? Did you extend Chart like I did, or another control? At one point, I gutted ExpeDataChart to just be a renamed Chart and it still didn't work. But, when I replaced it with a regular Chart, it did work. It seemed to very much not want to work with the extended ExpeDataChart until I  moved it to another project.

Comment: I extended `Chart` class. I did it in two ways (by adding a simple class that inheriting from Chart and by adding a User Control derived from Chart). I was able to add both of those to the form using the designer. I used VS 2010 Express and a console project with WinForms form (butI suppose this should not make any difference in this case).

Comment: @LukaszM - does the designer work after you close and reopen the VS solution? Or after you 'clean' the solution (which I believe deletes files in the _bin_ and _obj_ subdirectories)?

Comment: When I closed VS, removed the files from *bin* directory and then reopened the solution, I've got error in the designer (because it's the same assembly for both application and user control). However, then I rebuilt the project, closed the *Form (designer)* tab, reopened it and it worked correctly again (I had to close and reopen the tab, the opened tab was not automatically fixed after the build). Either way, it seems to work correctly when form and user controls are in the same assembly.

Comment: @LukaszM - thanks, I understand now. But this makes it 'sort of' work - hardly 'correctly', or productively. For example, if your source code is in version control and is used by multiple developers, every developer needs to know how to deal with the error. This isn't efficient for configuration management.

Comment: It seems that the workaround described by @LukaszM won't work if the target build is x64, because VS is a 32-bit app. If you don't want to extract the user control to a separate project, set the default build to x86 as mentioned in [one answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878169/vs-2010-designer-error-could-not-find-type-xyz-in-windows7-works-fine-in-xp).

Comment: Once You build the application, it works correctly. When You put controls to another assembly, use it in a form and then remove bin directories and reopen the solution (or just download it from the source control), I suppose the same error will appear ;). In either case, the issue is caused by missing dll and the fix is to compile it :). It's reasonable to keep user controls in another project, however, I suppose that it does not fix the missing dll issue, just changing dll file required :).

Comment: It did not work correctly when I built the application. This problem has been going on for about a month for me, with plenty of successful builds in the meantime. It was only today that it got annoying enough that I decided to seek help for a fix.

Comment: @LukaszM - "I suppose the same error will appear". You can try this without source control; I'm not sure you will get the error because VS is smart, e.g. it dynamically compiles the user control at the time you add it to a project. I think the key is here: _Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced._

Comment: I just tested this and the error appeared. Anyway, the issue described in question might have been caused by the platform settings You mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the file *ExpeDataChart.cs* to a separate project, a library project. The new project can be part of the Visual C# solution, or a separate solution,  e.g. *CustomControls*. Then add a reference to the library project to the project that uses the custom control. Now you should be able to edit the custom control using the visual designer.

Comment: That is a ridiculous solution that has to be implemented, but this fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @kingcoyote - no problem and thanks for confirming. But why ridiculous? The visual designer works with controls that were _previously_ compiled, which of course isn't the case when the custom control source is part of the current project.

Comment: It just seems like an arbitrary hoop to jump through. But I suppose it makes sense that the designer for this project can't work with custom controls from this project due to compile order issues.