# Visual C# Stop Code Generation For Custom Control

Tags: c#, charts, designer

Hope I can get some help with my problem, might be a simple fix. I'm trying to create a custom chart control (inheriting from the Chart class). In my constructor, I'm adding a ChartArea and Legend. Everything is fine when I add the control to the form, but when I run it, I get an error in the form designer saying a chart area already exists with the same name as the one I added in the constructor. So my problem is that the chart area is trying to be added a second time in the form designer generated code. I could remove this from the generated code but I wanted to see if there was an easier way to control it in my custom chart class. The constructor code for the chart is:

```
    public MultiFunctionalGraph(DataForGraph dataA, DataForGraph dataB, DataForGraph dataC, DataForGraph dataD)
    {
        this.dataA = dataA;
        this.dataB = dataB;
        this.dataC = dataC;
        this.dataD = dataD;

        ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
        Legend legend = new Legend();
        Axis xAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.X);
        Axis yAxis = new Axis(chartArea, AxisName.Y);

        chartArea.Name = "ChartArea";
        chartArea.Visible = true;
        this.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);
        legend.Name = "Legend";
        this.Legends.Add(legend);

    }
```

And I get this in the code generation in the designer:

```
        this.Graph1 = Graph();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.Graph1)).BeginInit();

        // Graph1
        // 
        this.Graph1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 5D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.Interval = 10D;
        chartArea1.AxisX.MajorTickMark.Interval = 5D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Interval = 500D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.Interval = 500D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MajorTickMark.Interval = 500D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorGrid.Interval = 500D;
        chartArea1.AxisY.MinorTickMark.Interval = 500D;
        chartArea1.CursorX.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
        chartArea1.CursorX.LineWidth = 2;
        chartArea1.CursorY.LineColor = System.Drawing.Color.LimeGreen;
        chartArea1.CursorY.LineWidth = 2;
        chartArea1.Name = "ChartArea";
        this.Graph1.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);
        legend1.AutoFitMinFontSize = 5;
        legend1.Name = "Legend";
        legend1.TextWrapThreshold = 20;
        this.Graph1.Legends.Add(legend1);
        this.Graph1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(46, 302);
        this.Graph1.Name = "Graph1";
        this.Graph1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(569, 300);
        this.Graph1.TabIndex = 7;
        this.Graph1.Text = "Graph1";
```

So basically I have to stop generating the code to add the chart area in the designer. I think I can get it using the DesignerSerialize attribute somewhere but I could really use some help. Thank you!

Comment: Have you __a)__ tried to remove the generated ChartArea before adding yours? __b)__ considered using a different name, which would mena to live with 2 ChartAreas from the start or __c)__ simply using the generated ChartArea?

Comment: My problem is that in the constructor of the custom chart I am adding a chart area, say "ChartArea1". When I add this chart to the form, the generated code in the designer automatically adds this same line, so it adds a chart area named "ChartArea1". Now that the same thing is being called in both the designer and constructor, I am trying to add two chart areas with the same name, which blows up. I need to somehow have the designer not generate that code.

Comment: Hm. Just came across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503427/inheriting-user-controls-in-c-sharp-net-2010) post. Is your custom Chart in a separate library project?

Comment: It's in the same project as the form I'm trying to add it to. I also came across that post but didn't think much of it as I wasn't getting anywhere close to the same problem as posted. It wouldn't hurt to put it in a separate library project I suppose.. I'll give it a try.

Comment: If you succeed, please do keep us posted! tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved it in a round about way. Instead of extending the Chart control, I extended the UserControl class and added a chart object in there. Now I can control it much easier with less hassle. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

In the graphical designer, open the `ChartAreas` collection property on the `Chart`, and remove anything currently there.

ETA: You can also do this programatically, in the constructor after the `InitializeComponent` method is called:

```
public MyChartClass()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ChartAreas.Clear();
    ChartAreas.Add("ChartArea");
}
```

Comment: This works, but its not quite the path I'm trying to take. I did resolve the problem in a round about way though, thank you for the input.